# Custom ListView with RadioButton single choice

Tags: android, android-listview, radio-button

I hope that some of you can help me with this:

I got a custom listview with
2 textviews and 1 radio button.

**I want to make it as a single choice, but everytime I
click on a item on the listview, it doesn't remove the
"check" from the other radio button.**

My xml code:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvMaterialName"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="MaterialName"
            android:textSize="35px" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvMaterialNo"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="MaterialNo"
            android:textSize="1px"
            android:visibility="invisible" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rdBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:checked="false" />
</LinearLayout
```

And my onItemClickListener:

```
searchList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {

            LinearLayout item_view = (LinearLayout) v;
            RadioButton itemcheck = (RadioButton) item_view
                    .findViewById(R.id.rdBtn);

            itemcheck.setChecked(true);
            if (itemcheck.isChecked()) {
                itemcheck.setChecked(true);
            } else {
                itemcheck.setChecked(false);
            }
           }

    });
```

My getView() in my adapter

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder viewHolder;
    final Materials materialItem = getItem(position);
    parent.setClickable(true);

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {

        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.d, null, false);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.tvMaterialName = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.tvMaterialName);
        viewHolder.tvMaterialNo = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.tvMaterialNo);

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

    }

    viewHolder.tvMaterialName.setText(materialItem.getMaterialName());
    viewHolder.tvMaterialNo.setText(materialItem.getMaterialNo());

    return convertView;
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Post code of `getView()` of CustomAdapter.

Comment: what is your list type, I mean the item in the list.

Comment: I have posted my getView from my adapter now :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try like this :

```
public class CheckedLinearLayout extends RelativeLayout implements
    Checkable {

private boolean isChecked;
private List<Checkable> checkableViews;

public CheckedLinearLayout (Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
        int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    initialise(attrs);
}

public CheckedLinearLayout (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    initialise(attrs);
}

public CheckedLinearLayout (Context context, int checkableId) {
    super(context);
    initialise(null);
}

public boolean isChecked() {
    return isChecked;
}

public void setChecked(boolean isChecked) {
    this.isChecked = isChecked;
    for (Checkable c : checkableViews) {
        c.setChecked(isChecked);
    }
}
public void toggle() {
    this.isChecked = !this.isChecked;
    for (Checkable c : checkableViews) {
        c.toggle();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onFinishInflate() {
    super.onFinishInflate();

    final int childCount = this.getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < childCount; ++i) {
        findCheckableChildren(this.getChildAt(i));
    }
}

/**
 * Read the custom XML attributes
 */
private void initialise(AttributeSet attrs) {
    this.isChecked = false;
    this.checkableViews = new ArrayList<Checkable>(5);
}

/**
 * Add to our checkable list all the children of the view that implement the
 * interface Checkable
 */
private void findCheckableChildren(View v) {
    if (v instanceof Checkable) {
        this.checkableViews.add((Checkable) v);
    }

    if (v instanceof ViewGroup) {
        final ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) v;
        final int childCount = vg.getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < childCount; ++i) {
            findCheckableChildren(vg.getChildAt(i));
        }
    }
}
}
```