# Radio button not working perfectly in listview

Tags: android, listview, radio-button

I have a list view in which I have list items populated dynamically. Each list item has a radio button.I want that if one list item's radio button is selected then other one must be de selected but it is not working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom ListView with RadioButton single choice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22630339/custom-listview-with-radiobutton-single-choice)

Comment: show your work please .

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the data list and set the Radio button for each row (except the one currently selected) to un-selected. And then you can call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this you should use singleChoice ListView with custom layout containing radio button.
You can take a look at a bunch of answers/articles about how to use singleChoice ListView.

For example:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/12823457/1533933
- http://tokudu.com/post/50023900640/android-checkable-linear-layout
  etc